# How to find tuples in a table if and only if the tuple appears once?

Tags: relational-algebra

I have a table:

```
x | y | z
------------
1 | 1 | *
1 | 1 | *
1 | 3 | *
2 | 2 | *
2 | 3 | *
3 | 4 | *
3 | 4 | * 
3 | 3 | *
```

What is a relational algebra expression to find tuples in a table if and only if the tuple appears once?

For example, I would like the following (x,y) tuples returned for the table above: (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), and (3,3).

If we imagine the X to be an ID, y to be some date, and z to be some event. I want the (id, date) tuples for people who only went to one event on that date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Rename R to S

   S := ρ<sub>S/R</sub>(R)
2. Join R and S on x,y

   D := R ⋈<sub>S.x = R.x ∧ S.y = R.y</sub> S

   This squares the number of tuples with a particular value for (x,y). Particularly, if a value for (x,y) appears only once in R, it appears only once in D.
3. Join R and S on x,y,z

   E := R ⋈<sub>S.x = R.x ∧ S.y = R.y ∧ S.z = R.z</sub> S

   This basically adds some columns to R. It does not add or remove tuples.
4. Subtract E from D and project to the attributes of R

   F := π<sub>x,y,z</sub>(D\E)

   This removes the tuples from D, that where created by joining a tuple from R to the corresponding tuple in S. The remaining tuples are the ones that where created by joining a tuple in R to a different tuple in S. Particularly, if a value for (x,y) appears only once in R, no tuple in F exists with that value.
5. Remove the tuples in F from R

   R\F

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The * was meant to be any value. Why can't my table have (x,y,z) tuples such as (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2) and (1, 3, 2). Is my question nos solvable if I perform a natural join on the table with itself, using a set of conditions, followed by some sort of set difference?