# "Exactly one" in Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

Assume relational database schema

```
PEOPLE = {ID, Lastname, Firstname}
CAR = {PID, Color}
FK PID ⊆ PEOPLE{ID}
```

The relational algebra I used is [image] from Fundamentals of Database Systems, 7th Edition (Global Edition), R. Elmasri and S. Navathe, 2017.

I want to query that the Lastname and Firstname of people who have exactly one Car in Blue.

It should be something like

```
π FirstName,LastName (
    σ (Color =′Blue′)∧(Count=1) (
        PEOPLE ⋈ (ID=PID) CAR
        )
    )
```

I don't know whether there is Count in Relational Algebra.

Comment: exists exactly 1 = exists 1 and and not exist 2 PS FKs need not exist, be known or be declared to query

Comment: There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & a reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Show parts you can do. Explain re how you are 1st stuck/unsure. PS It is no helpful to just dump some code.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [How to find all tuples in a table if and only if the tuple appears once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19482046/3404097)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. PS I linked to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know whether there is Count in Relational Algebra.

Let's start from here.

Relational Algebra (RA) as originally defined by Codd (basically, what is shown in the Table 8.1 you've posted—plus
renaming) is as expressive as First-Order Logic (FOL). That's one of Codd's fundamental
contributions (*Relational Completeness of Data Base Sublanguages*, 1972).

It is known that FOL has limited counting capabilities. Without entering into too many formal details, it is enough to
know that in FOL (with equality) you can say “there are up to *k* elements…” and “there are at least *k* elements…” for a **fixed** *k*. Let's see a couple of examples of the latter, which is easier to grasp:

- “there is (at least) one element in the domain” is ∃x.x=x
- “there are at least two (distinct) elements in the domain”: ∃x∃y.x≠y
- “there are at least three (distinct) elements in the domain”: ∃x∃y∃w.x≠y ∧ y≠w ∧ w≠x

etc. “There are at most *k* elements” is then equivalent to “It is not true that there at least *k+1* elements” (i.e.,
the negation of one of the formulas above).

You can then express that “there are exactly *k* elements”, because that's equivalent to “there are at least *k*
elements and it is not true that there are at least *k+1* elements”.

Note that *k* is fixed priori: different *k* require writing different formulas (note that the higher the count the more
quantifiers you need). The same phenomenon happens in RA (see below): the higher the count, the more (copies of)
relations you need.

Incidentally, you **cannot** count arbitrarily in FOL. You cannot express something like “the domain has even
cardinality” or “the number of elements with property P is the same as the number of elements with property Q (no matter how many of them there are)”.

Given Codd's result, if something can be expressed in FOL then it can be expressed in Codd's RA. And if something cannot be
expressed in FOL, then it cannot be expressed in Codd's RA.

So, since you can express “there is exactly one element” in FOL, then you can definitely do so in RA. How? In the same
way: “there is at least one… and there do not exist two or more…”.

Let's see how all that applies to your example: we need to find the names of people of have at least one car, but who do
not have at least two cars. First, finding the names of people who have at least one car is easy (in what follows, I use
`<-` as assignment to split the query into simpler steps, and assign arbitrary names `A`, `B`, etc. to the intermediate
relations):

```
A <- п FirstName,LastName (PEOPLE ⨝{ID = PID} CAR)
```

Next, how do we find people that do *not* have at least two cars? When a query has a condition with a negation or
a universal (“…such that there are not…”, “…such that for all…”), you'd better answer the query with the negated,
existential, condition (“…such that there are…”, “such that there exists… not…”) and then take a difference.

So, we first solve: “people who *do* have at least two cars”. This is an existential statement, and pretty easy
to express with joins in RA:

```
CAR' <- RENAME {C_PK -> C_PK', PID -> PID', Color -> Color'}(CAR)  # CAR' is a copy of CAR with primed attributes
B    <- CAR ⨝{C_PK ≠ C_PK' ∧ PID = PID'} CAR'                      # People with at least two cars
C    <- п FirstName,LastName (PEOPLE ⨝{ID = PID} B)                # Names of people with at least two cars
```

Note that I have added an attribute `C_PK` to CAR playing the role of the primary key. Every relation must have
a primary key, and {PID, Color} obviously doesn't work for CAR (how would someone own two red cars, otherwise?). I won't comment further on that, to focus on the specific question.

Note also that it would be trivial to change the above query to find people who own at least three/four/five… cars: just make
more copies of `CAR` and join them as in `B` (look carefully at the parallel between the inequalities in `B` and the
inequalities in the FOL formulas for “there are at least *k*…” above).

Now, the people who do *not* have at least two cars are all the people except those who own at least two cars. That's now trivial to compute (RA
difference plays the role of logical negation):

```
D <- (п FirstName,LastName (PEOPLE)) - C
```

Therefore, the people who own exactly one car are those in `A ∩ D` (people who own at least one car and do not own two
cars or more—intersection plays the role of logical conjunction).

This query can be optimized, but that's left as an exercise.

To wrap it up:

> I don't know whether there is Count in Relational Algebra.

Not in RA as originally defined by Codd (the algebra we have used in this exercise). You can still count to some extent, as I hope I have clarified above.

But RA can be extended to increase its expressivity, and many theoreticians and books have done so (the book you cite
does so, IIRC). Hence, you will find descriptions of RA which include count() functions, group-by operators, etc. The
extensions are mostly motivated by the desire to study the theoretical properties of practical languages such as SQL.
For instance, in SQL you can build a (one row by one column) table whose content is the number of records in some table.
You cannot do that in Codd's RA. But you can do it in a version of RA extended with the equivalent of SQL count().

Comment: Of course, any other condition (e.g., the cars must be blue) can be easily added as additional filters to the above queries.